# Securities traded in different currency

Tags: stock-market, accounting

Excuse me if this is not the site to ask this question but I read in meta that you have a accounting tag so here we go.

If I made a buy of an ETF in two different exchanges  with different currencies (same Isin, different currency see [this question in personal money and finance exchange](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24336/how-does-it-work-when-the-same-etf-is-listed-on-several-stock-exchanges?newreg=3b2d0d98a5b646078c494aa365662125)) and I'm valuing this securities at fair value. I have to take the ETF as the same or different security? (i.e. makes some difference the currency of the exchange)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see why you would price an ETF at fair value and not at last market price, given that those funds are very liquid. But in either cases you need to have two distinct securities in your portfolio, as the two classes of shares that you own in the ETF bear different risks, and will yield different performances, due to the xrate.

Comment: Thanks for answer, ok assume that I value them with the last market price. If they are the same security but traded in a different exchange with different currencies how should I consider them? Value each one with the currency of the trade, or one is free to value them in the currency of election.